# Shortcut to add task into specific product backlog item in TFS 2013 web view

Tags: shortcuts, team-foundation-server

Is anyone aware of a quicker way to add a new task to a specific product backlog item in the web view of TFS 2013?

Ideally a shortcut, but anything quicker than going into backlog, finding the product backlog item you want a new task adding to then clicking add.

The TFS query shortcuts (pin to homepage etc) suggest that there may be a shortcut lurking around somewhere for the backlog, but I cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching there is a small "create new" link on the home page to a collection next to the "Work" item.

[image: Screen Capture]

Clicking this enables the user to create a new task. A new window appears.

If the user the clicks on "LINKS" they can link the new task to any product backlog item if they know its individual work item ID.